# Get user logged on sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I need to create notifications for every user who didn't read a specific new on the site.
To do this i need to see who user is logged in the site and then save this info into a list on Sharepoint.
The problem is that i don't know where can i get this info on Sharepoint Online.

Someone can help me whith this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the Current Login User Object with this endpoint.

`/_api/web/currentuser`